# What does a well ordering of $\mathbb{R}$ look like?

Tags: real-analysis, order-theory, axiom-of-choice

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a known well ordering of the reals?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6501/is-there-a-known-well-ordering-of-the-reals)

I am having a hard time wrapping my head around what a well-ordering of $\mathbb{R}$ looks like. I have seen the presentation of a well-ordering of $\mathbb{Z}$ ie $0, -1, 1, -2, 2, \ldots$ but how could you do this type of ordering with $\mathbb{R}$ where numbers are not countable in that way?

Edit: I'm guessing what I'm asking is if $0, -\epsilon , \epsilon, -2\epsilon, 2\epsilon,\ldots$ could be thought of as  a well-ordering of $\mathbb{R}$ in a similar fashion.

Comment: The well-ordering **requires** (part of) the Axiom of Choice, so we will not be able to exhibit one.

Comment: Try this out:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29237/the-well-ordering-principle

Comment: Try  [Is there a known well-ordering of the reals](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6501/is-there-a-known-well-ordering-of-the-reals), or [A way to well-order real line](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150992/a-way-to-well-order-real-line).

Comment: Also: [Explicit well-ordering of $\mathbb{N^N}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/23927/16627) and the MathOverflow thread [V=L and a well-ordering of the reals](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/6593/vl-and-a-well-ordering-of-the-reals)

Comment: Take the any of real numbers, then take any of the rest, again take any of the rest. Continue till the end of time.

Comment: @Norbert: If time is a continuum then you can only have a countable amount of steps.

Answer (score 10):

Nobody can wrap their head around a well-ordering of $\Bbb R$, and nobody knows what one looks like.  It is impossible to exhibit one.

$0, -\epsilon , \epsilon, -2\epsilon, 2\epsilon,\ldots$  cannot be a well-ordering of $\Bbb R$, because it is countable. (In particular, it omits $\epsilon\over 2$.)  A well-ordering of $\Bbb R$ must contain an uncountable sequence of elements of $\Bbb R$, which means that it is at least as complicated as $\omega_1$, the smallest uncountable ordinal.  This means that you would have to supply not only the first $\omega$ elements $0, -\epsilon , \epsilon, -2\epsilon, 2\epsilon,\ldots$, but then a following sequence corresponding to $\omega+1\ldots 2\omega$, and so on for every countable ordinal.  Countable ordinals are very complicated.

Comment: If it is impossible to exhibit (or see) such a well-ordering, ie mortals like myself have little intuition about such a thing, why is there so much faith that it is true, since AC=WO?

Comment: That is a very big topic, and one which has been addressed elsewhere on the site better than I could hope to do.

Comment: Possibly relevant to your question: [Advantage of accepting the axiom of choice](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/120925/advantage-of-accepting-the-axiom-of-choice), or [Unprovable statements in ZF](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/173530/unprovable-statements-in-zf), in which Asaf left a lot of links to related material.

Comment: @tacos_tacos_tacos one does not require faith that it be true.  One only requires faith that assuming it to be true will not lead to a contradiction.  And that, one can safely have.

Answer (score 5):

We don't know what a well-ordering of the real numbers looks like. Not only because it is a non-constructive object (i.e. its existence is provable, but not describable in ZFC), but also because the *length* of this well-ordering is undecidable in ZFC.

Namely, suppose that the real numbers could be well-ordered. Take an ordering of minimal length. Is this an order of length $\omega_1$? $\omega_5$? $\omega_{\omega_{\omega_1}}$?

The axioms of ZFC are not sufficient to calculate the exact length of the well-ordering of the reals; and the axioms of ZF are not sufficient to prove the existence of such well-ordering (but I wrote about this enough in the linked posts).

As for the elements? Well, that is impossible to tell if the set is not *canonically* well-ordered, like the natural numbers. Consider the rationals, those are well-orderable (it is a countable set). What is the least rational in the well-ordering? What is its successor? We can't *really* tell. We can always choose a well-ordering that its first element is $0$ and the second is $42$; we can describe a few more elements; we can even describe longer pieces. However there is no *canonical* way to do that.

Similarly even if the real numbers are well-orderable we can't really point out a particular well-ordering because of that. We can always take a permutation of the real numbers to define a new well-ordering.

Either way, however, describing only a countable part of the real numbers is not enough to describe a well-ordering of them all because Cantor's theorem tells us the real numbers are uncountable.

Comment: But the axioms of $ZFC$ do prove that $\omega_{1}$ embeds into a well ordering of the reals. Right?

Comment: If the real numbers can be well-ordered, then that well-ordering is uncountable, and therefore its order type is ***at least*** that of *the least* uncountable ordinal.